# How to make a grid so the cells are as square as possible with any given aspect ratio?

Tags: p5.js

I am drawing a grid of dots, is basically a nested array:

```
const colWidth = (p5.width / cols)
const colHeight = (p5.height / rows)


for (let x = 0; x < cols+1; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < rows+1; y++) {
    spots.push(Spot(p5, x * colWidth, y * colHeight))
  }
```

Spot is an object that accepts an x and y location.

The thing is, depending on the with and height of the window, the grid of dots gets stretched or squished, what I want, is that no matter which dimensions the window has, the grid stays as "squared" as possible,  I mean, that the squares made by the dots make a square shape instead of a rectangle, doesn't have to be 100% a square, just as close as possible given the window dimentions.

I tried, getting the proportion of the width and height in relation to each other, then multiplying that number by a subdivision number and then setting the cols and rows to the result, but that doesnt work. it still looks stretched.

```
let windowWidthProportion = p5.width/p5.height
let windowHeightProportion = p5.height/p5.width 

cols = windowWidthProportion * subdivision
rows = windowHeightProportion * subdivision
```

Any idea how to get this working? thanks.

My sketch:

```
export default function Sketch(p5) {
  ...
  
  function Spot(p5, x, y) {
    ...
  }

  p5.setup = (canvasParentRef) => {
    canvas = p5.createCanvas(p5.windowWidth, p5.windowHeight /*, p5.WEBGL*/)
 
    let windowWidthProportion = p5.width/p5.height // 200   
    let windowHeightProportion = p5.height/p5.width // 100

    cols = windowWidthProportion * subdivision
    rows = windowHeightProportion * subdivision

    const colWidth = (p5.width / cols)
    const colHeight = (p5.height / rows)

    p5.background(0);
    for (let x = 0; x < cols+1; x++) {
      for (let y = 0; y < rows+1; y++) {
        spots.push(Spot(p5, x * colWidth, y * colHeight))
      }
    }
  }

  p5.draw = () => {
    ...
    spots.forEach((s, i) => {
      let { _x, _y, hovered } = s.values()
      s.randomWalk()
      s.display()
      if (i !== 0 && isOverGridPoint(p5.mouseX, p5.mouseY, _x, _y)) s.flash() 
      hovered && s.fade()
    })
  };
}
```

Comment: Without having had a close look at your code: if you want any dimensions to be independent of your window size, don't make them rely on the window size, and if you want squares, you need to use the same measurements/variable for length and height.

Comment: So you could e.g. have a look at the window's width and height just to know what your frame of reference is, then pick the smaller of the two and use that as the basis to build your squares.